# IONIC: Java SDK Version Not Matched

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I cannot debug my `Ionic Capacitor` application to android emulator. I am using Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip.

after I ran this command:

```
ionic cap run android -l --external
```

This is what I got at then end:

```
[capacitor] ✖ Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] 
[capacitor]         > Configure project :app
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         > Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]         WARNING::                             Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
[capacitor]         Currently detected usages:
[capacitor]         - repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
[capacitor]         - repository flatDir2 used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
[capacitor]         This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
[capacitor]         See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
[capacitor]         Currently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':byteowls-capacitor-filesharer', ...
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:writeDebugAarMetadata
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResValues
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-camera:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:extractDeepLinksDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-push-notifications:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugManifest
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :byteowls-capacitor-filesharer:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
[capacitor]         > Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7a5491eb
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[capacitor]         > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[capacitor]         > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 2s
[capacitor]         57 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 51 up-to-date
[capacitor]         
[capacitor] Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

After some researches, people are saying that the java JDK version is wrong (Or is it?).

How can I know match the JDK version for my project and Android Studio?

This is my java version:

```
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7, mixed mode)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using Java 11 SE Version for Capacitor 4 , here you can find the instruction for Gradle And JAVA
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0